# I am trying to add a filter to a existing vba that will filter and display results on a report where field [Potential Discrepancy Amount] is not null

Tags: ms-access, vba

The section that I added is:

```vb
If Not IsNull(Me.[Potential Discrepancy Amount]) Then
    strCurrency = "Potential Discrepancy Amount = True"
End If
```

I have also attempted several other options but nothing that I attempt actually works. Without a filter I receive all records which I could usually handle with a filter in the actual report, however it is throwing the layout and grand totals off for other columns within the report.

```vb
Private Sub RunReport_Discrepancies_button_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    Dim strReport As String
    Dim strDateField As String
    Dim strWhere As String
    Dim strCurrency As String
    Dim lngView As Long
    Const strcJetDate = "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"

    strReport = "Discrepancies"
    strDateField = "[Audit Date]"
    lngView = acViewPreview

    If IsDate(Me.start_audit) Then
        strWhere = "(" & strDateField & " >= " & Format(Me.start_audit, strcJetDate) & ")"       
    End If
    If IsDate(Me.end_audit) Then
        If strWhere <> vbNullString Then
            strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
        End If
        strWhere = strWhere & "(" & strDateField & " < " & Format(Me.end_audit + 1, strcJetDate) & ")"
    End If

    If strWhere <> "" Then
        strWhere = strWhere & " AND "
    End If

    strWhere = strWhere & "[Pharmacy NPI] = '" & Me.NPI_List.Value & "'"

    If Not IsNull(Me.[Potential Discrepancy Amount]) Then
        strCurrency = "Potential Discrepancy Amount = True"
    End If


    If CurrentProject.AllReports(strReport).IsLoaded Then
        DoCmd.Close acReport, strReport
    End If

    Debug.Print strWhere
    DoCmd.OpenReport strReport, lngView, , strWhere
    Exit_Handler:
    Exit Sub

    Err_Handler:
    If Err.Number <> 2501 Then
        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Cannot open report"
    End If
    Resume Exit_Handler         

End Sub
```

Comment: Bracket the field name in your string: `strCurrency = "[Potential Discrepancy Amount] = True"`

Comment: You haven’t added strCurrency to your filter- you create strCurrency but then open the report using strWhere. Did you want to add strCurrency to strWhere, or did you want to replace strWhere with strCurrency?

Comment: I bracketed the field name and also added strCurrency after the strWhere clause, but it is still not filtering on only those records where [Potential Discrepancy Amount] is not null.
I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Since you already have `Debug.Print strWhere`, run the code, go the Immediate window and copy that string.  Then create a simple query (`SELECT * FROM YourTable`) in the Access query designer, switch to SQL View, add `WHERE` plus a space followed by the text string you copied earlier.  When you run that query, presumably it will not display the results you want, so revise it to return the correct results.  You can flip back and forth between Design View and SQL View to make the needed adjustments (it's the same query either way, just presented differently).  Once you have the query working ...

Comment: as you wish, revise your VBA code to create the working `WHERE` clause, without the word `WHERE`.